# Handle different language and target levels for sources and tests with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm interested if someone has clue how to handle this pom in projects properties of IDEA:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <source>1.3</source>
       <target>1.3</target>
       <testSource>1.5</testSource>
       <testTarget>1.5</testTarget>
   </configuration>
   <version>3.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Should I set project level 1.3 and module level 1.5 or wise verse around?

As well anytime when IDEA reloads maven project it sets language levels as it thinks from maven to 1.3 and after always complaints about test classes.

But this will go as bug report to JetBrains.

Comment: There is already an open bug report for this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81494

Comment: Defect: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85478

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Supporting test source/target levels is tracked by [this request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85478). Language level changed message is also a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81494).

Comment: Thank you Sergey, I hope Dev team will pick up this soon, since it's really annoying. But maybe there are not many people who supports ancient products

Comment: Six years have passed and the issue is still unresolved. :-( Looks like we have to use one of the proposed workarounds.
More relevant than ever, since certain test libraries depend on the latest language features and the release cycle of the Java language is now faster than back then.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned different language levels for main and test sources are not yet supported by Idea.

There's a workaround to force Idea to use the language level defined in `testSource` when importing Maven project. You can create a separate Maven profile only for Idea with different compiler plugin settings:

```
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <testSource>1.8</testSource>
                        <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>ide</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>idea.maven.embedder.version</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <testSource>1.8</testSource>
                        <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profile>
```